# Building GWT plugin for FireFox 10 on FreeBSD 9

Tags: firefox, gwt, gcc, freebsd

I tried to follow the instructions on http://www.sigil.org/gwt-on-freebsd/ for building the plugin for the most recent version of Firefox. However linking fails with the error:

```
g++ -o build/FreeBSD_x86_64-gcc3-ff100/libgwt_dev_ff100.so build/FreeBSD_x86_64-gcc3-ff100/ExternalWrapper.o build/FreeBSD_x86_64-gcc3-ff100/ModuleOOPHM.o build/FreeBSD_x86_64-gcc3-ff100/FFSessionHandler.o build/FreeBSD_x86_64-gcc3-ff100/JavaObject.o build/FreeBSD_x86_64-gcc3-ff100/JSRunner.o build/FreeBSD_x86_64-gcc3-ff100/Preferences.o build/FreeBSD_x86_64-gcc3-ff100/XpcomDebug.o ../common/libcommon64.a -fPIC -shared -m64 -L../../../plugin-sdks/gecko-sdks/gecko-10.0.0/FreeBSD_x86_64-gcc3/lib -Wl,-rpath-link,../../../plugin-sdks/gecko-sdks/gecko-10.0.0/FreeBSD_x86_64-gcc3/lib -lxpcomglue_s -lxpcom -lnspr4 -lmozalloc -lxul
    build/FreeBSD_x86_64-gcc3-ff100/ExternalWrapper.o: In function `GenericClassInfo':
/home/bofh/tmp/gwt_build/trunk/plugins/xpcom/../../../plugin-sdks/gecko-sdks/gecko-10.0.0/FreeBSD_x86_64-gcc3/include/nsIClassInfoImpl.h:132: undefined reference to `vtable for GenericClassInfo'
/usr/bin/ld: build/FreeBSD_x86_64-gcc3-ff100/ExternalWrapper.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against `_ZTV16GenericClassInfo' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
gmake: *** [build/FreeBSD_x86_64-gcc3-ff100/libgwt_dev_ff100.so] Error 1
```

I'm not sure why it complains about missing -fPIC flag because it is present in command line for g++.

Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

the problem was because of wrong SO library used - the one installed by libxul doesn't provide required function, so I copied libxul.so and libxulglue_s.so from firefox installation

and I was able to build the plugin successfully.

=====

after all, I was able to build latest GWT plugin for FreeBSD 9 / Firefox 10 / AMD64, see https://github.com/jdevelop/gwt-dev-firefox-freebsd

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you install it via ports; `/usr/ports/www/xpi-gwt-dev-plugin`.

If you don't want to do that, at least try applying the patches that the port uses. The patches `files/patch-config.mk` and `files/patch-xpcom-Makefile` look relevant to this issue.

Comment: the port doesn't work for me

xpi-gwt-dev-plugin-2.0_2 cannot install: unknown Firefox version: firefox-3.5